# Routing System for Custom Framework with Symfony Components

Tags: php, oop, symfony, routes

[image]

My directory Structure is shown above. I am trying to build a Framework with Symfony Components. but one problem, when I hit a route that I defined, it doesn't give me back the response.

Here is my index.php

```
<?php

$loader = require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$loader->register();

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

require 'lib/Framework/Core.php';
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();

// Our Framework is now handling itself the request
$app = new Framework\Core();

$app->map('/', function () {
    return new Response('This is the home page');
});

$app->map('/about', function () {
    return new Response('This is the about page');
});

$response = $app->handle($request);
```

and my Core.php looks like this

```
<?php namespace Framework;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface as HttpKernelInterface;

class Core implements HttpKernelInterface
{
    protected $routes = array();

    public function handle(Request $request, $type = HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST, $catch = true)
    {
        $path = $request->getPathInfo();

        // Does this URL match a route?
        if (array_key_exists($path, $this->routes)) {
            // execute the callback
            $controller = $this->routes[$path];
            $response = $controller();
        } else {
            // no route matched, this is a not found.
            $response = new Response('Not found!', Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
        }

        return $response;
    }

    // Associates an URL with a callback function
    public function map($path, $controller) {
        $this->routes[$path] = $controller;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what the bug is? What did I screw up?

Comment: Why don't you use the much more flexible symfony Routing component? (btw, did you look at [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/)?)

Comment: I know about the routing component, I am following a tutorial on how to build a Framework with Symfony Components. Just for experience. and I know about Silex, but what I need is to get this fixed so I can go on and understand how to work this out

Comment: Are you just missing the last part that actually sends the response (sends the headers and content)? $response = $app->handle($request); $response->send();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, you're just missing the last little detail (->send()) where you tell the Response object to send the headers and echo the content. So:

```
$response = $app->handle($request);
$response->send();
```

And I think that should do it!

Cheers!